# Convert a two-step LINQ query into a single LET query?

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have the following code:

```
var data = /* enumerable containing rows in your table */;
var part = "X";
var items = new HashSet<int>(data
    .Where(x => x.PartName == part)
    .Select(x => x.ItemName));
var query = data.Where(x => items.Contains(x.ItemName));
```

`items` finds all items in data with a specific `PartName`.

`query` returns all records in data for that item.

I need to convert this into a single LET statement (or something else) that I can use embedded in another larger LINQ query.

For example, if my data is as follows (records):

```
ItemName PartName
1        A
1        B
2        A
3        C
```

And I am looking for items with part "A" I need the end result to be:

```
1        A
1        B
2        A
```

One suggestion was to do something like this:

```
let a = data.GroupBy(x => x.ItemName)
            .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.Partname == part))
            .Select(g => new
                {
                    ItemName = g.Key,
                    PartNames = g.Select(x => x.PartName)
                })
```

However the data returned in (let a) doesn't match the expected results, this returns something like:

```
1        A,B    // list of parts for that item
2        A
```

And I need to keep the same pre-existing structure as shown above.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sound like you need `SelectMany` from group:

```
   data.GroupBy(x => x.ItemName)
            .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.PartName == part))
            .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = /* enumerable containing rows in your table */;
var part = "X";
var query = data.Where(x => data
    .Where(d => d.PartName == part)
    .Any(d => d.ItemName == x.ItemName));
```

Comment: `Contains`!  this will not compile, i think you should use `Any`. But this is not good way to solve the problem.